# How to import multiple sheets from multiple excel files into one list- readxl R

Tags: r, excel, function, loops, import

I have seen other posts that detail how to import multiple sheets from a single excel file into R, and also how to import a series of excel files that have a single sheet in each, but not the two at the same time.

I am able to make the following code work in pieces at an individual file level, but I think I may be screwing up the loop somehow in some simple way.

When I execute the loop, I only get output from the first member of the list (files[1]) instead of output from all iterations of the loop appended in the all_data list object.

Here's my code:

```
# name filepath of excel files to import
file_path ="..."

# load names of excel files 
files = list.files(path = file_path, pattern = ".xlsx", )

# create list to store data
all_data = list()

# create function to read multiple sheets per excel file
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
  x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(x) <- sheets
  }

# execute function for all excel files in "files"
for (i in length(files)){
  filename = paste0(file_path,"/", files[i])
  read_excel_allsheets(filename)
  all_data = c(all_data, x)
  }
```

I suspect I'm just making a fundamental loop mistake, but have searched around and can't find out how to fix. any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Couple of comments: list.files has `full.names` argument, so you dont have to prepend path. `read_excel ` returns tibbles, so you dont need to coerce it to data.frame. Inside the loop, you did not assign result of `real_excel_allsheets()` function to a variable (I guess it should be x). You created an empty list and grow it inside the loop. Pre-allocate it to `length(files)` and assign by element `i` instead

Comment: is the data in all the files/tabs the same structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple sheets within multiple Excel files, you need nested looping. Consider nested `lapply` calls. Specifically, return the appropriate object as right now it returns *sheets* for every call of function. Then, convert `for` to `lapply` for a list of objects:

```
# load names of excel files 
files = list.files(path = "...", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".xlsx")

# create function to read multiple sheets per excel file
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  tibble_list <- lapply(sheets, function(sh) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = sh)
  df_list <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
  names(df_list) <- sheets                 

  return(df_list)
}

# execute function for all excel files in "files"
all_data <- lapply(files, read_excel_allsheets)
```

Even name you *all_data* list by each file's basename:

```
# name outer list
xl_base_names <- lapply(files, basename)
all_data <- setNames(all_data, xl_base_names)
```

---

Alternatively, shorten your function and use `sapply(..., ..., simplify = FALSE`) which by default names list by supplied character vector:

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  sapply(sheets, function(f) as.data.frame(readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = f)), 
         simplify = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: that's really helpful- thank you for making time to explain!!

Answer (score 1):

see if something like this works for you:

```
library(readxl)
library(fs)
library(purrr)

file_names <- dir_ls("folder_name",
                     glob = "*.xlsx", ignore.case = TRUE)

x <- map_df(file_names, function(x){  
                 sheet_names <- excel_sheets(x)
                 raw_data <- map_df(sheet_names, ~read_excel(x, sheet = .x)) 
                 return(raw_data)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that returns a data frame with columns for file and sheet names for each file. In this example, not every file has the same sheets or columns; test2.xlsx has only one sheet and test3.xlsx sheet1 does not have col3.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

dir_path <- "~/test_dir/"         # target directory where the xlsx files are located. 
re_file <- "^test[0-9]\\.xlsx"    # regex pattern to match the file name format, in this case 'test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx' etc.

read_sheets <- function(dir_path, file){
  xlsx_file <- paste0(dir_path, file)
  xlsx_file %>%
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(read_excel, path = xlsx_file, .id = 'sheet_name') %>% 
    mutate(file_name = file) %>% 
    select(file_name, sheet_name, everything())
}

df <- list.files(dir_path, re_file) %>% 
  map_df(~ read_sheets(dir_path, .))

# A tibble: 15 x 5
   file_name  sheet_name  col1  col2  col3
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 test1.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     4
 2 test1.xlsx Sheet1         3     2     3
 3 test1.xlsx Sheet1         2     4     4
 4 test1.xlsx Sheet2         3     3     1
 5 test1.xlsx Sheet2         2     2     2
 6 test1.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     4
 7 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     3     5
 8 test2.xlsx Sheet1         4     4     3
 9 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     2
10 test3.xlsx Sheet1         3     9    NA
11 test3.xlsx Sheet1         4     7    NA
12 test3.xlsx Sheet1         5     3    NA
13 test3.xlsx Sheet2         1     3     4
14 test3.xlsx Sheet2         2     5     9
15 test3.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     1
```