# R to Merge All Sheets From All Excel Files

Tags: r, xlconnect, readxl

I am trying to merge data from all sheets in all Excel files in a folder.  All sheets and all files have the same headers and same data sets.  I thought the code below would read all sheets, but it seems to be reading ONLY the first sheet in each file.

```
# This needs several other packages
# install.packages("XLConnect")
require(XLConnect)

setwd("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/R Programming/Excel/Excel_Files/")

fpattern <- "File.*.xls*?"  # pattern for filenames
output.file <- "Test.xls"
lfiles <- list.files(pattern = fpattern)

# Read data from all sheets
lfiles %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, lfiles = lfiles)
```

Comment: Where's the problem exactly? There's a lot of code there after where you say the problem is. If it's not needed, please make the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: Well, I think  I highlighted the problem, right.  At least as well as I understand it.  I think this is it: lfiles %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, lfiles = lfiles)
That seems to pull data from the first worksheet in the workbook, but not all worksheets in the workbook.

Comment: Unlike other QA sites, here on SO, the questions are editable; please edit your question to reflect where the problem is (and to remove the unneeded code).

Comment: I just tried to simplify my question.

Comment: Much better, thanks. One more suggestion: the `readxl` package is the "latest and greatest" way to read Excel files; if you can switch to that, you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using only R base functions and XLConnect:

```
library(XLConnect)

testDir <- "Excel_Files"

re_file <- ".+\\.xls.?"
testFiles <- list.files(testDir, re_file, full.names = TRUE)

# This function rbinds in a single dataframe
# the content of multiple sheets in the same workbook
# (assuming that all the sheets have the same column types)
rbindAllSheets <- function(file) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
  sheets <- getSheets(wb)
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(sheets, function(sheet) {
            readWorksheet(wb, sheet)
          })
  )
}

# Getting a single dataframe for all the Excel files
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(testFiles, rbindAllSheets))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following does what you're looking for. In this example, not every file has the same sheets or columns; test2.xlsx has only one sheet and test3.xlsx sheet1 does not have col3. It also labels the file and sheet name for each file.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

dir_path <- "~/test_dir/"         # target directory where the xlsx files are located. 
re_file <- "^test[0-9]\\.xlsx"    # regex pattern to match the file name format, in this case 'test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx' etc.

read_sheets <- function(dir_path, file){
  xlsx_file <- paste0(dir_path, file)
  xlsx_file %>%
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(read_excel, path = xlsx_file, .id = 'sheet_name') %>% 
    mutate(file_name = file) %>% 
    select(file_name, sheet_name, everything())
}

df <- list.files(dir_path, re_file) %>% 
  map_df(~ read_sheets(dir_path, .))

# A tibble: 15 x 5
   file_name  sheet_name  col1  col2  col3
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 test1.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     4
 2 test1.xlsx Sheet1         3     2     3
 3 test1.xlsx Sheet1         2     4     4
 4 test1.xlsx Sheet2         3     3     1
 5 test1.xlsx Sheet2         2     2     2
 6 test1.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     4
 7 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     3     5
 8 test2.xlsx Sheet1         4     4     3
 9 test2.xlsx Sheet1         1     2     2
10 test3.xlsx Sheet1         3     9    NA
11 test3.xlsx Sheet1         4     7    NA
12 test3.xlsx Sheet1         5     3    NA
13 test3.xlsx Sheet2         1     3     4
14 test3.xlsx Sheet2         2     5     9
15 test3.xlsx Sheet2         4     3     1
```

Comment: Hello there.  This looks pretty close, but something in my setup must be different than yours.  I'm getting this result: df
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: file_name <chr>, sheet_name <chr>
What is this for?  re_file <- "^test[0-9]\\.xlsx" 
Also, what is this for?  .id = 'sheet_name'

Comment: re_file is the regex pattern `list.files()` uses to get the xlsx file names in the directory. In this example it matches any file that matches with the naming format 'test[single digit].xlsx', but looks like you could do just `re_pattern = 'File.*\\.xlsx'`. `.id = 'sheet_name'` just adds the sheet name as a column. You could replace 'sheet_name' with whatever you wanted the column to be. It is an optional argument.

Comment: I keep getting this result: # A tibble: 0 x 0
I guess it's not detecting any of the files.  Before, I was getting the first sheet of each file, but now I'm not getting anything at all.  Ugh.

Comment: It could be a problem with the regular expression to match the file name formats. Does calling just `list.files(dir_path, re_file)` list out the files you're expecting?

Comment: And if the `list.files()` call works as expected, then try the `read_sheets()` function with a just single file name: `read_sheets('~/sample/path/', 'sample_file_name.xlsx')` and see if that works as expected.

Comment: I found another solution, from here, which worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200887/how-to-import-multiple-sheets-from-multiple-excel-files-into-one-list-readxl-r
I think your solution looks fine, but some small thing must be off, and it's preventing me from fetching data from those Excel files.  Thanks, though.  I marked your answer as helpful.  Again, I think the problem is on side.

Comment: How could we only include sheets matching a certain pattern? 
Changing ```excel_sheets() %>% set_names() ``` to ```(grep("Sheet[1-2]",value=T,ignore.case=T,excel_sheets()) %>% set_names() ``` creates an error later in the ```map_df```